# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/confluent/connect/avro/AvroConverterConfig

Tags: avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

kafka2.12-2.4.0  confluent5.4.1

I am trying to use Confluent's Schema-register.
But when I start schema-register and connect-Distributed.
Connect logs did not report errors.

[image]

connect-avro-distributed.properties

```
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://k2:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://k2:8081
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
plugin.path=/usr/local/tools/confluent-5.4.1/share/java,/usr/local/tools/kafka/kafka_2.12-2.4.0/plugin
```

I have configured the confluent jar address so that connect can find the class. (plugin.path)

But when I POST the conector request.

```
{
"name": "dbz-mysql-avro-connector",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
    "database.port": "3306",
    "database.user": "debezium",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.debezium.mysql.avro",
    "database.password": "123456",
    "database.server.id": "184124",
    "database.server.name": "debezium",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://k2:8081",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://k2:8081",
    "table.whitelist": "debeziumdb.hosttable",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "k1:9092,k2:9092,k3:9092"
}
```

}

Throw the Exception.

```
[2020-04-23 10:37:00,064] INFO Creating task dbz-mysql-avro-connector-0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:419)
[2020-04-23 10:37:00,065] INFO ConnectorConfig values: 
    config.action.reload = restart
    connector.class = io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector
    errors.log.enable = false
    errors.log.include.messages = false
    errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
    errors.retry.timeout = 0
    errors.tolerance = none
    header.converter = null
    key.converter = class io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
    name = dbz-mysql-avro-connector
    tasks.max = 1
    transforms = []
    value.converter = class io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig:347)
[2020-04-23 10:37:00,065] INFO EnrichedConnectorConfig values: 
    config.action.reload = restart
    connector.class = io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector
    errors.log.enable = false
    errors.log.include.messages = false
    errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
    errors.retry.timeout = 0
    errors.tolerance = none
    header.converter = null
    key.converter = class io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
    name = dbz-mysql-avro-connector
    tasks.max = 1
    transforms = []
    value.converter = class io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig$EnrichedConnectorConfig:347)
[2020-04-23 10:37:00,067] INFO TaskConfig values: 
    task.class = class io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TaskConfig:347)
[2020-04-23 10:37:00,067] INFO Instantiated task dbz-mysql-avro-connector-0 with version 1.1.0.Final of type io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:434)
[2020-04-23 10:37:00,067] ERROR Failed to start task dbz-mysql-avro-connector-0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:470)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/confluent/connect/avro/AvroConverterConfig
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.configure(AvroConverter.java:61)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.newConverter(Plugins.java:293)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.startTask(Worker.java:440)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.startTask(DistributedHerder.java:1140)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.access$1700(DistributedHerder.java:125)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$13.call(DistributedHerder.java:1155)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$13.call(DistributedHerder.java:1151)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2020-04-23 10:37:00,071] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Finished starting connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1125)
```

[image]

All jars are in this directory.

Now what can I do to allow the class to be introduced, or does the version of confluent not exist in the class?

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest using Docker. Then you don't have classpath issues

Comment: I saw your answer in another post, but that did not solve my problem. I went back and tried docker. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this exception.

I did not use the confluent platform, just installed the schema-registry component.

To be precise, I only installed the community version and only activated the schema-registry component.

Then I downloaded the Avro jar package on the official website, and finally put it in the plugin completely, and started the connect successfully.

[Confluent Avro jar address](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-avro-converter)

And, I executed the following statement so that it can be read.

```
export CLASSPATH=/usr/local/tools/kafka/kafka_2.12-2.4.0/plugin/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `kafka-connect-avro-converter` is not compatible with other confluent jars. your Q does not list the `kafka-connect-avro-converter` jar as well. Can you add the correct version jar of `kafka-connect-avro-converter` in your classpath.